# CNN labels Jpeg to Tif - number of labels change during greyscale

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, python-imaging-library

I have used application dash_doodler to make some label data to train a CNN (https://github.com/Doodleverse/dash_doodler/tree/main) which is the primary use of this package.

However, it returns RGB Jpegs. For my CNN I need these to be 1 band tifs. The dash_doodler comes with some scripts to turn it into different formats but as far as I can tell not what I need.

So far I have tried this:

```
import os, sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import skimage

fn = r"FILEPATH"
output_folder = r'FILEPATH'

def jpegtoTif(fn, folder):
    # open dash_doodler output 
    im = Image.open(fn)

    #file name unimportant to question
    ofn = fn.split('\\')[-1][:6]+'.tif'
    ofn = os.path.join(folder, ofn)

    # greyscale 
    im = im.convert('L')

    # resize: hardcoded to orginal tif size before it was converted to 
    # jpeg for dash doodle
    im = im.resize((5235, 10298))
    
    # np to change values..
    im = np.array(im)
    # 101 needs to be 0 98 need to be 1 
    im[im==101]=0
    im[im==98]=1

    # used skimage to save but could have converted back to pil object
    skimage.io.imsave(ofn, im)
    
jpegtoTif(fn, folder)
```

I need to reclassify the output to 0 or 1 but was expecting max 3 classes, instead the greyscale has given me many, is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I realised the resize might be the issue - tried moving it to after the renaming values. used np.resize(im, (5235, 10298)). This gave a completely wrong result of what looked like random scatter.

Comment: Please add some images to your question so we know what you are referring to. An input image and its corresponding actual and expected output image would be useful.